# How to use property pages on unregistrated filter?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow, multimedia

I use filter DS LAME for compressing audio. I loaded it from file "lame.ax" as follows:

```
// pPath - path to LAME "lame.ax"
HRESULT CMyFilter::CreateObjectFromPath(wchar_t *pPath, REFCLSID clsid, IUnknown **ppUnk)
{
    // load the target DLL directly
    if (!m_hLibFilter) m_hLibFilter = LoadLibrary(pPath);
    if (!m_hLibFilter)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    // the entry point is an exported function
    FN_DLLGETCLASSOBJECT fn = (FN_DLLGETCLASSOBJECT)GetProcAddress(m_hLibFilter, "DllGetClassObject");
    if (fn == NULL)
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    // create a class factory
    IUnknownPtr pUnk;
    HRESULT hr = fn(clsid, IID_IUnknown, (void**)(IUnknown**)&pUnk);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IClassFactoryPtr pCF = pUnk;
        if (pCF == NULL)
        {
            hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
        else
        {
            // ask the class factory to create the object
            hr = pCF->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IUnknown, (void**)ppUnk);
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

further

```
HRESULT hr = 0;
IUnknown *ppUnk = 0;
ULONG lRef = 0;    
hr = CreateObjectFromPath(L"lame.ax", CLSID_LAMEDShowFilter, (IUnknown **)&ppUnk);
hr = ppUnk->QueryInterface(&m_pFilter);
lRef = ppUnk->Release();
```

It works perfectly. LAME encoding audio.

I want to show the filter settings - property page, but this code failed

```
bool ShowConfigWindow(HWND hParent)
{
    ISpecifyPropertyPages *pProp;
    HRESULT hr = m_pFilter->QueryInterface(IID_ISpecifyPropertyPages, (void **)&pProp);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the filter's name and IUnknown pointer.
        FILTER_INFO FilterInfo;
        hr = m_pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&FilterInfo);
        IUnknown *pFilterUnk;
        m_pFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void **)&pFilterUnk);

        // Show the page. 
        CAUUID caGUID;
        pProp->GetPages(&caGUID);
        pProp->Release();
        HRESULT hr = OleCreatePropertyFrame(
            hParent,                   // Parent window
            0, 0,                   // Reserved
            FilterInfo.achName,     // Caption for the dialog box
            1,                      // Number of objects (just the filter)
            &pFilterUnk,            // Array of object pointers. 
            caGUID.cElems,          // Number of property pages
            caGUID.pElems,          // Array of property page CLSIDs
            0,                      // Locale identifier
            0, NULL                 // Reserved
        );

        // Clean up.
        pFilterUnk->Release();
        FilterInfo.pGraph->Release();
        CoTaskMemFree(caGUID.pElems);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I find https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video/jknSbMenWeM

I should call CoRegisterClassObject for each property page, but how to do it?
Or what the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OleCreatePropertyFrame` takes property page class identifiers (CLSIDs) so you need to find a way to make them "visible" for the API.

Use of `CoRegisterClassObject` is one of the ways to achieve the mentioned task (perhaps the easiest, another method would be reg-free COM). You need to retrieve `IClassFactory` pointers for property page CLSIDs the same way as you do it in the first snippet. Then instead of calling `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` you use the interface pointers as arguments for `CoRegisterClassObject` API. Make sure you do it on the same thread as the following `OleCreatePropertyFrame` call. `CoRevokeClassObject` will clean things up afterwards.